# Why is this javascript code not running in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

 if (window.name == 'default') {
        window.name = 'a03d01c6c88549c6a7e05c922961271e';
        window.document.getElementById('ctl03').click();
    }
    else if (window.name == '') {
        window.name = 'default';
        window.document.getElementById('ctl04').click();
     }
    else if (window.name == 'invalidAccess') {
        if ('FALSE' == 'TRUE')
        {
         window.name='';
        window.document.getElementById('ctl04').click();
        }
        else
        {
            window.open('MsgPage_NewWindow.aspx','_self');
        }
    }
    else {
        window.name = 'invalidAccess';
        window.document.getElementById('ctl04').click();
    }
</script>
```

The above script is emitted on the page by a server control is a WebPage...  There is no other control in the page apart from the page... Internet Explorer redirects it to the page "Home.aspx", but Firefox just stays in the same page... Noteven it shows any error.

Could you please help.  I also would like to know the reason why so, as I have to make the entire web application work in FF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the proprietary IE-only `click` method to redirect.

You should write `location.href = "http://url";` instead; that will work in every browser.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking under Tools->Error Console? If you do you will see something like "click is not a function", try simply setting .location.